# Need to demote a DC with DNS and AD.

Tags: domain, domain-controller

I have only three users on it but is filesharing for many others. Security was not a major concern. Using one account for shared folder. Need to install software that doesn't like AD or DC. No users are authenticating to this DC. It is however running DHCP and DNS.
There are no other DCs onsite. Can I just demote and reconfigure DHCP/DNS?

Answer (score 1):

## Only DC in the domain

If you are ***absolutely 100% positive*** no one is:

- authenticating to the box, *and*
- you are not using any Active Directory functionality for your sharing (such as AD groups for permissions on the share), *and*
- you have no dependencies on AD such as Exchange Server or some other LDAP-integrated product, *and*
- none of your machines are members of the domain the box is running, *and*
- there's no critical data in AD which you **depend** on for proper corporate operations (if this is the only DC in the domain), *and*
- ... *etc* ...

then there will be no harm in running `dcpromo` and demoting the box. It won't break anything, and you will be asked to set a local `Administrator` (or equivalent) password in the process, so you can log in after the demotion is complete.

---

My point with the above is that no one but *you* knows how your infrastructure works, so only you will be able to make the final call as to whether anything is actively relying on Active Directory/LDAP/Kerberos being around and available and whether the demotion is safe. In other words, be ***absolutely sure*** you don't depend on this box before pulling the trigger. It sounds like your network is simple and you know it well, so this should not be a problem, but have a backup plan if something does go wrong (such as a system state backup you can recover the box from).

If you have a complex DNS setup, make sure you take backups or notes before the demotion, especially if the zone is AD-integrated, since that is likely to be lost. Non-AD-integrated zones should not be, provided you do not remove the DNS service.

DHCP is likely "authorized" to be operable by writing data into the configuration partition of your forest, and hence may require partial re-configuration.

---

## Multiple DCs in the domain

Of course, if you have multiple DCs in the domain, which is unclear from your saying:

> There are no other DCs onsite

then the demoted box just becomes a member of the domain. At that point, you will need some form of cross-site connectivity to chat back with other DCs for the domain to stay up, but presumably you have this already otherwise AD would have been very unhappy not being able to communicate with its replication partners. Demoting the box just makes it a member server and you continue as before, with local configuration of DHCP / DNS services as necessary.